# Ubuntu 20.04: reboot error with nomodeset (dis)enabled

Tags: boot, 20.04, nomodeset

My computer has only Ubuntu 20.04 as OS since March (when I became a linux user) and just worked fine. Yesterday I was cleaning the room and accidentally shooted off the operating computer from the energy supply. As I turned on today, I noticed a black screen with the following message:

```
recovering journal
/dev/sda5: clean, 656[...] files, 34[...] blocks
```

Searching for explanations didn't help. I've tried some tricks. At GRUB in recovering mode I tried:

```
sudo fsck -f /
/dev/sda5 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting
```

I typed `reboot` and it didn't solve. Then I tried:

```
journalctl -xb
```

I pressed PageDown to read all the messages. And one of them told me about that nomodeset was enabled [image: nomode]

But it isn't! I searched as root for

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

And there's no mention about nomodeset.[image: grub]
When I asked for edit `e` on the normal Ubuntu booting, it also showed no especification.
I would really appreciate some tips.